# How to speed up pattern matching

Tags: performance-tuning, pattern-matching

#### Main Problem

Mr.Wizard posed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8484299/) when discussing another problem.

I reproduce the main part of Mr.Wizard's problem here:

```
MatchQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {x__?((Echo[##]; False) &), y__}]
```

On evaluation we get the result:

> ```
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> False
> ```

The result is correct of course, and there should be four possible patterns, but it seems that, though `MatchQ` already knows the element `1` cannot pass the pattern test, it continues matching `1` three more times.

The extra matching is okay here as evaluation is fast enough, but this will consume a lot of time while matching long lists or dealing with patterns with long evaluation times, such as `x__?((Echo[##]; Pause @ 1; False)&)`

So the main problem is:

**how to speed this process up and aviod repetitive calculation.**

---

#### Some more explanation

I think some work-around is needed to get better results:

1. Unlike `Condition`(`/;`), `PatternTest` will check every element in a `__?test`-like pattern, not putting everything together. Thus this two pattern matching is different, and they give different results:

   ```
   MatchQ[{1, 2, 3}, {__?((Echo@{##}; True) &)}];

   MatchQ[{1, 2, 3}, {x__ /; (Echo@{x}; True)}];
   ```

   > ```
   > {1}  
   > {2}
   > {3}
   > {1,2,3}
   > ```

Thus, in most cases, there'll be no problem of interference while using `PatternTest`; for example, testing `1` in `Sequence[1, 2]` will usually be the same as testing `1` in `Sequence[1, 2, 3]`. While in `Condition`, interference will be significant.

2. There are a few examples of interference. Take, for example, the answer of @Leonid Shifrin under the question I've mentioned at the beginning:

   ```
   Module[{flag = False},
     ClearAll[test3]; 
     test3[x_] := 
       With[{fl = flag}, If[! flag, flag = True]; 
       Echo @ x; 
       fl]];
     MatchQ[{-1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {x__?test3, y__}];
   ```

   > ```
   > -1
   > -1
   > 2
   > ```

But I think these cases usually won't occur, so I still want to know: are there any methods available to tell Mathematica, "I know testing result of elements will be the same in each trial, SKIP the repeated testing!"?

---

#### Some Notes

- I do **NOT** need a way to store the result of the pattern test, I'm trying to reduce the testing repetitions.
- The latter one will speed up the simple pattern matching process in long lists considerably; the first one won't, as the pattern test completes in a flash, but there're are simply too many flashes, thus the overall speed is low.
- Actually, the sample match I used as an example, the four tests complete in a flash, so memoizing will not speed things up. But if we can avoid the testing of the latter three `1`, the whole process will be 4 times faster!

---

#### Additional and related examples

Here is an additional example that may help illustrate the inefficiency of reapplying the same test to the same element.

```
Replace[
  {1.1, 2.2, 3, 4, 5},
  {a___, x__?((Print[##]; IntegerQ[#]) &), y__} :>
    {{a}, {x}, {y}}
]
```

> 1.1
>
> 1.1
>
> 1.1
>
> 1.1
>
> 2.2
>
> 2.2
>
> 2.2
>
> 3
>
> ```
> {{1.1, 2.2}, {3}, {4, 5}}
> ```

This causes an algorithmic explosion in the time taken to process this pattern.  In most applications it would be better if each element were only tested *once.*  Observe that a test of a list of 200 elements performs almost twenty thousand tests:

```
i = 0;
MatchQ[N@Range[200], {a___, x__?((i++; IntegerQ[#]) &), y__}]
i
```

> ```
> False
>
> 19900
> ```

This is not simply a matter handing the somewhat unusual case of a stateful test function (like the one with `flag`) as it is baked into expressly stateless patterns as well:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[
  MatchQ[#, {a___, x__Integer, y__}] &,
  RandomReal[99, #] &
  , "IncludeFits" -> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Is my question clear enough to emphasize our points?

Comment: @Wjx I think the question is quite clear.  Thank you for posting it.  I added additional examples that I *hope* serve to illustrate the issue at a fundamental level without getting too far afield.

Comment: I'm just going to edit it to include a similar case: `MatchQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {___?((Echo[#, 1]; True) &), __?((Echo[{#, # > 2}, 2]; # > 2) &), __?((Echo[#, 3]; True) &)}]` :)

Comment: After a more careful reading I realized your intent. Why not apply the test beforehand to all elements, cache the result and then pick your match according to the precomputed results?

Comment: Regarding the "some notes" section: I realize my suggestion doesn't reduce the number of tests in the simple example, but it could prevent the O(n^3) behavior in the edit.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Actually, I will classify this kind of "evaluate once to speed up" as memorization as I've mentioned in the post. This will not speed up these pattern matching process as the speed of simple calculation is almost as fast as reading the calculation result. Also, this type of method will not prevent the O(3) behavior I suppose? As the test match's count will not decrease.

Comment: My suggestion is to go a bit further and reimplement the matching - ditch entirely the `PatternTest` function, compute the tests and roll a more intelligent matcher. We have determined in the linked question, that a completely general approach is not possible, but it should be doable for specific cases.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I agree. But it's quite hard to do so......

Comment: This is far off from a complete solution, but illustrates my intent: `args = Range[1., 100.]~Join~{101, 102}~Join~Range[102., 200.]; f[x_ /; Length[
     Split@Total@
       Boole@Through[{Map[True &], Map[IntegerQ], Map[True &]}[x]]] ==
     3
  ] := "Hurrah!"; f[args]`

Comment: Wjx, I've written up something that goes in the direction of an answer. The main idea is to -- by precomputing the tests -- prevent MMA from generating *all* possible combinations of `{x__, y__, z__}` and only then applying `?IntegerQ` to *every* generated `y`

Answer (score 7):

For `MatchQ` you can use `Return[.., MatchQ]`:

```
MatchQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {x__?((Echo[##]; Return[False, MatchQ]) &), y__}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I suspect one would like this to work with function argument checking, which it won't:

```
ClearAll[foo];
foo[{x__?((Print[Stack[]]; Return[False, MatchQ]) &), y__}] := "Hurrah!";

foo@Range@5
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The output of `Stack[]` shows there's no function that can be substituted for `MatchQ` that would cause a return just from argument checking.

On the other hand, one could use `MatchQ` for checking the argument pattern:

```
ClearAll[foo];
foo[arg_] /; MatchQ[arg, {x__?((Echo[##]; Return[False, MatchQ]) &), y__}] := "Hurrah!"

foo@Range@5
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The logic of this use-case is simple enough to allow this simple optimization.  One can imagine a more general question of how to find the optimal check on a given pattern. My feeling is that is impractical to solve. But one might be able to apply code-optimization techniques to the problem.

Comment: I'll have to say that this answer will do the job, but only for my far too simple  illustrative code, instead of pattern matching in general. A simple alternation from `MatchQ` to `Cases` and return `False` only when inputing `1` will make this kind of solution fail. Its implementation is too narrow, actually not quite what I want.

Comment: @Wjx I don't understand your simple alternation.  `Cases[{{1}}, a_ /; MatchQ[a, {x__?((...; Return[False, MatchQ])&), z__}]]`?  Or perhaps you could clarify what you do want?  (I can't fix something that's working on the example problem, obviously.)

Comment: Check @Mr.Wizard 's update~

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment which may take some time to develop into an answer.

I'll focus on the O(n^3) algorithmic behavior observed on the benchmark plot and ways to combat that. I will not, however, handle the problem in the very first example (where four pattern tests were performed). I believe, one will need to essentially rewrite a pattern matcher, based on a more intelligent testing of conceivably valid combinations, in turn based on precomputed pattern tests.

Consider the example pattern `{x__, y__?IntegerQ, z__}`.

```
args = Range[1., 100.]~Join~{101, 102}~Join~Range[103., 200.];
```

Now I'll precompute the tests:

```
Boole@Through[{Map[True &], Map[IntegerQ], Map[True &]}[args]];

MapIndexed[# Last@#2 &, %, {2}];

pos = DeleteCases[%, 0, {2}];
```

And `pos` will have a list of lists, the first containing matching positions for `x__`, then for `y__?IntegerQ`, then for `z__`.

Next filter out obviously invalid positions (by invalid, I mean, that `x__` must end before `y__?IntegerQ` ends and `z__` must begin after `y__?IntegerQ` starts):

```
Do[pos[[i]] = Select[pos[[i]], # < Max[pos[[i + 1]]] &];
  pos[[i + 1]] = Select[pos[[i + 1]], # > Min[pos[[i]]] &];, {i, 
   Length[pos] - 1}];
pos

(*
  {{1,2,...,101},
   {101,102},
   {102,103,...,200}}
*)
```

Now is the tricky part which may be vulnerable to "algorithmic explosion". From this list of positions I wish to select permissible end-points of every pattern.

```
pos = pos~Join~{Length[args] + 1};
Do[pos[[i]] = Cases[pos[[i]], Alternatives @@ (pos[[i + 1]] - 1)], {i, Length[pos] - 1}];
pos = Most@pos
(* {{100, 101}, {101, 102}, {200}} *)
Tuples@%
(* {{100, 101, 200}, {100, 102, 200}, {101, 101, 200}, {101, 102, 200}} *)
Select[%, # === Union@# &]
(* {{100, 101, 200}, {100, 102, 200}, {101, 102, 200}} *)
```

Let's return the possible ways the original pattern can match our symbol `args`:

```
Internal`PartitionRagged[args, Differences[{0}~Join~#]] & /@ %
(*{
   {{..., 100.}, {101}, {102, 103., 104., ...}},
   {{..., 100.}, {101, 102}, {103., 104., ...}},
   {{..., 100., 101}, {102}, {103., 104., ...}}
  }
*)
```

So by precomputing 200 tests it was possible to somewhat analytically reduce the number of combinations of arguments to 3, rather than 14752 calls to `IntegerQ`.

This guide should work for any amount of `BlankSequence` but there's a lot of bulletproofing to do here as well as early detection of outright non-matches. Hopefully, this can be a starting point for further efforts.

Addendum:
I checked the performances of my `Cases` statement with the following test:

```
BenchmarkPlot[
 With[{r = {Range[3 #], Range[2 #, 4 #]}}, 
   Cases[First@r, Alternatives @@ (Last@r)]] &,
 # &,
 "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

O(n log(n)) is probably the bottleneck of this method and is quite a bit better than n^3.

Comment: An intellegent try I shall say. but using this type of pattern matching style, you do can battle against the O(n^3) explosion, but if the whole list change to `Range[1000]`, you will still need to list out all possible matches first before selecting one of them, but the current pattern matcher can simply check once, taking almost no time, and give you a result, actually, much faster. Can you edit your post to include this feature? I mean, find the solution in some order, then quit evaluation as soon as you get a result.

Comment: My thought is to check possible matches still in a pattern matching way, but using some techniques to aviod repetitive checks and matches. But as you can see, seeking some way to manipulate the pattern matching process is quite hard......

Comment: @Wjx You're right, it's much easier to find if a match is possible, than to return all possible matches. It'll take some work to optimize, for which I don't have time ATM. It'd be an interesting project to reimplement the pattern-matcher for this restricted problem that you posed.

Comment: Yes~ if this can be achieved, a lot of similar problems shall be solved too~ As you can see, mostly we're just using this form of simple patterns. :P

Comment: @Wjx scratch that, my posted function was wrong. Let me try and find a fix.